# change height and width in image url using javascript regex

Tags: javascript

URL: `www.abc.com/2778152_Ice_Purple?wid=120&hei=120&op_sharpen=1`

I want to change wid=500 and hei=500 using regex only.

current code:

```
"www.abc.com/2778152_Ice_Purple?wid=120&hei=120&op_sharpen=1".replace(/(wid=")\d+("\W+hei=")\d+/, '$1500$2500')
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, please show your attempt and explain where you have struggled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not accurate one but working :

```
"www.abc.com/is/image/kohls/2778152_Ice_Purple?wid=120&hei=120&op_sharpen=1".replace(/wid=\d+/, "wid=500").replace(/hei=\d+/, "hei=500");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with a regex method but you could try just doing it [the old fashioned way.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)
Alternatively, after mentioning the document element in your code you could put ".width = *value*;" or ".height = *value*;" which can be done a few different ways.

If there's a specific reason you NEED to use regex, please explain.